# How can I import the content of an HTML file into a <div> without it acting like an object?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm currently importing an HTML file into a `<div>` like this:

```
function load_content() {
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%" data="./content.html"></object>';
}
```

And this works, the content is on the page.  But, it's acting like its own object with a scrollbar on the side (almost like it's a frame), when really I just want the `<div>`s in the external file to show up on the page onto which I'm importing as if I wrote them on that page.

How can I do this, and without jQuery?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use AJAX?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: this is a CSS layout issue.

Comment: Does `content.html` contain an entire document (*`<html>`..`</html>`*) or just the template of the content you want to insert..?

Comment: @t-j Just a template!

Answer (score 2):

You could use an Ajax request, something like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        if (this.status === 200 && this.responseText !== null) {
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    }
};

xhr.open("GET", "content.html");
xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method to insert specific content from a remote file:

> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded.

For example,

```
$("#result").load( "ajax/test.html #container" );
```

The element with an ID of container inside `test.html`, along with its contents, will be inserted into the element with an ID of result

Comment: Is there a way to do this without jQuery, though?